# Meteor,unable to send verification email

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to send verification mail but it showing some error

my error is `URI malformed`

First,error screenshot

[image]

I added email package and at the server side i added something like

```
 Accounts.config({
             sendVerificationEmail:true
         });
```

i set env_url like this

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://postmaster%sandbox.mailgun.password@smtp.mailgun.org:587';
```

Comment: any one need more info regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URIs use [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for reserved characters, and a `%` by itself is invalid. Also, there should be a `:` between the username and the password (see the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#email)). This should be the format you want:

```
'smtp://postmaster%40sandbox.mailgun:password@smtp.mailgun.org:587'
```

which decodes to:

```
'smtp://postmaster@sandbox.mailgun:password@smtp.mailgun.org:587'
```

Comment: Yeah i forgot to add 40 after %.Thx it's working now

Comment: if you have special character in your password, don't forget to convert them using this:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp